# How to exclude certain string values via regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am a beginner when it comes to `regex`. I have string `cn=foo,ou=bar,ou=zoo,ou=aa,ou=bb,ou=cc,ou=dd,o=someOrg,c=UK`. I need to get `foo,bar and zoo` so I used following regex to extract string in javascript.

```
const dn = 'cn=foo,ou=bar,ou=zoo,ou=aa,ou=bb,ou=cc,ou=dd,o=someOrg,c=UK';
const regex = /^cn=(\w+),ou=(\w+),ou=(\w+)/;
const found = dn.match(regex);
console.log(found) --> Array ["cn=foo,ou=bar,ou=zoo", "foo", "bar", "zoo"]
```

Then `ou=bar` value is changed upon new requirement to `ou=bar - 1`. It could have `-` or `numeric` value in any order within that string value. I tried following regex.

```
const regex = /^cn=(\w+),ou=(.+),ou=(\w+)/;
```

however it returns unwanted data `Array ["cn=foo,ou=bar,ou=zoo,ou=aa,ou=bb,ou=cc,ou=dd", "foo", "bar,ou=zoo,ou=aa,ou=bb,ou=cc", "dd"]`

What I expect is `Array ["cn=foo,ou=bar - 1,ou=zoo", "foo", "bar - 1", "zoo"]`. I tried to exclude unwanted data via `^(ou=aa|ou=bb|ou=cc|ou=dd|o=someOrg|c=UK)` within the regex but I got `null` value. I'd appreciate someone can help me to correct regex syntax.

Update:

I tried `/^cn=(\w+),ou=(\w+\s+-\s+\d+),ou=(\w+)/` but this covers it above example but it won't cover something like `ou=bar-1` or `ou=1bar-`..

Comment: I think you might want to use an existing library for parsing LDAP addresses rather than using a regex, especially as LDAP paths can contain special characters and escape sequences which are non-trivial to handle correctly with a regex: http://www.selfadsi.org/ldap-path.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easies way to solve this task is to make it non-greedy (notice the question mark!):

```
const regex = /^cn=(\w+),ou=(.+?),ou=(\w+)/;
```

Alternatively, you may want to exclude the comma:

```
const regex = /^cn=(\w+),ou=([^,]+),ou=(\w+)/;
```

Comment: LDAP path values can contain commas and other special characters and its has its own escaping rules - so the latter idea might not work: http://www.selfadsi.org/ldap-path.htm